# What are the steps in writing Desktop client for Jboss 7.1

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss7.x, java-ee-5

I recently created standalone client for Glassfish 3.2, now I want my application to be deployed on JBoss. I am interested in answer which will guide me to build standalone application which will interact with my EJB 3 application that will be deployed on JBoss 7.1

My another sub question is: which should be the preferred choice for creating standalone client: EJB 3.0 or WebServices ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that you're mixing some things up here.

First, what do you mean by "standalone client"? If you deploy something on an application server, then this is not standalone, but it's a piece of server software which can be used by clients.

Next, a client of your business code (which for example is implemented in an EJB), can of course be another local or remote EJB, but then this is again some piece of server software using your functionality. If you want that to be used from the outside, then you have to provide access to it for example in form of a web service.

And finally, you speak of "JBoss 7.1" and "Glassfish 3.2" and a recently created application - then go and drop usage of EJB3.0 and JEE5 immediately and make use of the current JEE6 with EJB3.1 and all of it's related technology. The included REST API for example might be a good choice for implementing a client. This client then in turn can be a "desktop application" (e.g. native Java application or JavaFX application) which makes use of your business logic exposed via the REST service.

Comment: All you are talking about is REST (Web Services), I will go for it but if you can point out steps for running remote application that interact with my EJB 3.0 based application deployed on JBoss then it will be great for me to get over the concept. I have deployed EJB 3.0 application on server and I'm using standalone application (desktop application) over intranet that interact with the server. I achieved this functionality by copying some jar files from glassfish's modules directory at client side and made some changes in properties file for JDNI lookup based on my server IP address/name.

Comment: There are two types of applications: 1) Application Client - desktop application running on the same computer, your server application (glassfish/jboss) is running on 2) standalone client - desktop application which is running somewhere else on internet/intranet

Comment: @SudhirDhumal: No matter if your client is running on the same computer or another one - it does not run within the EJB container, so you have to go via the network stack. You can achieve that by using an application client container (that is basically what you did by copying jar files, except that each application server provides a defined way of using its container from an application client module), which allows you to use injection mechanisms. You can as well go via JNDI lookups and get references to EJBs that way. BUT - you shouldn't go either way.

Comment: @SudhirDhumal [continued]: The reason for that is, that you directly use EJBs from the outside, which was indeed an idea in the early J2EE times, but today is not common at all. Instead, your EJB should expose some of its logic (coarse grained while the EJB can have fine grained methods) via a defined interface to the outside, e.g. via a SOAP or REST webservice. Then your client can use this well defined interface regardless of the used container, the EJB details and the language the client is programmed in.